# Trouble accessing Raspberry pi 2 GPIO with python

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a scenario in which i have to take readings from a DHT11 Temperatute & Humidity sensor and publish it to a topic (I am using python so suggestions keeping python in mind would be helpful). The problem is that i need to do sudo to assess the GPIO but again rosrun is not found when in sudo. What should i do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229435/trouble-accessing-raspberry-pi-2-gpio-with-python/) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try to use the search next time (or Google: `$searchterms site:answers.ros.org` fi), this has been asked (and answered) many times before. See [Raspberry Pi 2, ROS and GPIO access](http://answers.ros.org/question/216441/raspberry-pi-2-ros-and-gpio-access/) for a recent one.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-18**:
But that case uses the WiringPI Library for C++. I am trying to do this with Python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-18**:
The question I linked as an example. There are many more, and also dealing with Python.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-18**:
Also: [WiringPi/WiringPi-Python](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python).

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-21**:
Wiringpi2 says its deprecated and wiringpi still requires sudo. What should i do ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-21**:
From `_wiringpi2/README.txt`:

> This package has been deprecated in favour of using the name "WiringPi" which provides the same exact functionality.

It's just a name change.